# Unable to open a package(module) inside another package using a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have imported a package which was downloaded from the link "https://github.com/moritz-wundke/android-page-curl", then I created a new project and imported the downloaded package by clicking on "import module". I have added a button inside my new package to open the downloaded package. But its not working. Can someone help. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {

                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage
                        ("fi.harism.curl");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);


            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
}

Manifest:

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Layout:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="press"/>
```